# Get all results that are associated with current user in Parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, pfuser

I am trying to retrieve all objects that are in the column "Job_Title" that are associated with the the current user.

Currently I am only getting the first result in the table each time.

I want all objects, there should be 5 for this user that is logged in.

```
    let query5 = PFQuery(className: "jHistory")
    query5.whereKey("createdBy", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    query5.skip = 2
    query5.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if (objects != nil) {
            // The find succeeded.
            for object in objects! {

                let jobTitle = object["Job_Title"] as! NSString
                self.job_Title.text! = "\(jobTitle)"
                print(objects)

            }

        }

        else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are skipping the first two (`query5.skip = 2`) - so there are 3 jobs created by that user and 2 you have skipped, the result is one. The user could have jobs not `createdBy` herself.

You should check your `whereKey` and use the usual relationship predicate.

Comment: thanks I am now managing to output all 5 results to the console, but not sure how to get all 5 results to dispay on the screen when using              let 
jobTitle = object["Job_Title"] as! NSString
                self.job_Title.text! = "\(jobTitle)"